# What does bash -l do and why can't it find ssh?

Tags: bash, windows

I have GitBash installed in a windows 7 box and I'm trying to figure out why running:

```
bash -l ssh
```

results in

```
Welcome to Git (version 1.9.0-preview20140217)

Run 'git help git' to display the help index.
Run 'git help <command>' to display help for specific commands.
bash: /bin/ssh: No such file or directory**
```

If I do `bash -l` and after login ssh, it all works fine, so what does `bash -l` does exactly?

PS: I'm asking this here because I want to know what `bash - l` does and I do not figure why I can't get it to work on GitBash.

Comment: "After login ssh". What happens if you run "/bin/ssh" instead?

Comment: Also, why are you running `bash -l ssh`?  What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Bash does not, by default, take a _command_ to run as an option - at least not according to `man bash` on my system. That's what the `-c` option is for; do you want `bash -l -c ssh`? The plain `bash -l ssh` starts a login shell and tries to run a file named ssh as a _shell script_, whereas your ssh is probably an executable.

Comment: Actually I'm trying to understand why I can't get Vagrant to login into the VM I created. From their [docs](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/vagrantfile/ssh_settings.html) it runs `bash -l` by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bash -l` call a login shell.

From `bash` documentation, [Invoking Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Invoking-Bash.html):

> -l
>
> Make this shell act as if it had been directly invoked by login. When
>   the shell is interactive, this is equivalent to starting a login shell
>   with ‘exec -l bash’. When the shell is not interactive, the login
>   shell startup files will be executed. ‘exec bash -l’ or ‘exec bash
>   --login’ will replace the current shell with a Bash login shell. See Bash Startup Files, for a description of the special behavior of a
>   login shell.